# Change image of listview item on click

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to change image of a list item on click.I have tried using view but on using it I am getting multiple items with changed image even though I just click on a single one.I am using a simplecursor adapter and code is same as given in this question:-[changing image on listview at runtime in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964562/changing-image-on-listview-at-runtime-in-android).

And also I don't want to use a custom adapter.It will be really helpful if someone helps me in solving this problem just through simple adapter.

Current code

```
  @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      /*
      imageView=(ImageView)l.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.PlayPause);


      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

      */
}
```

Comment: you need to do `ImageView ivImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.PlayPause);` 
`ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);`

Answer (score 1):

1- Do not use get child at when u are directly getting the child view as "View v" in the event.

2- you just need to call invalidate() method on the view once u set the new background resource.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  imageView=((ImageView)v)

  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

  imageView.invalidate();
```

}

While you should make your list using a simple cursor adapter with an imageview ---- :-

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

refer this link for that.

Comment: Its showing me ClassCastException error in imageView=((ImageView)v)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
ListView.OnItemClick(OnItemClickListener{})
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Comment: I am using on ListItemClick but its not possible to change image of just a single item using this.That's why I am looking for some alternative.

Comment: You should use v.findById(R.id.PlayPause); than l.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.PlayPause); in my opinon

Comment: I have tried it but it changes the images of several other items also.